# OpenCV + gstreamer pipline issue

Tags: python, gstreamer

I have this pipline which runs my Jetson camera using the command line with no problems:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z0JAKpWgHgCJ+VA\\=\\,aM48gA\\=\\=\",payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! autovideosink sync=false
```

I want to run it from a python script so I used this code (which I previously tested with a sample video from my pc and it was working).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

print(cv2.__version__)
width = 640
height = 480

#pipeline='videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! appsink'
#pipeline = 'filesrc location = sample.mp4 ! qtdemux ! queue ! h264parse ! omxh264dec !nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, format=BGRx ! queue ! videoconvert ! queue ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink'

pipeline = 'udpsrc port=5000 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z0JAKpWgHgCJ+VA\\=\\,aM48gA\\=\\\=\\", payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! appsink'
print("pipeline defined")

#'udpsrc port=5000 caps=\"application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z0JAKpWgHgCJ+VA\\=\\,aM48gA\\=\\\=\\",payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! appsink'
caps = cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(pipeline, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
print("pipeline passed to video capture")
if cam.isOpened():
    print("yes")
else: 
    print("no")
while cam.isOpened():
    _,frame = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow('myCam',frame)
    #cv2.moveWindow('myCam',0,0)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

how do I correctly represent the "caps" part in the pipeline as I feel it is what caused the error. I tried to add a \ before every " sign or use a double quotation mark in the middle but it didnt work. I also tried to set the caps as a seperate stage in the pipeline as the following:

```
udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z0JAKpWgHgCJ+VA\\=\\,aM48gA\\=\\\=\\", payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! appsink'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

decodebin internally selects subplugins for each type of parsing/decoding.
There is a ranking that allows to choose when several plugins are available for a type of decoding.
For H264 decoding, on Jetsons the highest rank would be nvv4l2decoder, that outputs into NVMM memory (in NV12 format unless otherwise specified) that is suitable for autovideosink that will instantiate plugin nvoverlaysink reading from NVMM memory.

For reading from OpenCv application, you would need frames in system memory, and better in BGR format for color frames.
So you would first convert NV12 in NVMM memory output of the decoder into BGRx format and copy into system memory with plugin nvvidconv. Then use CPU-based plugin videoconvert for conversion into BGR:

```
pipeline = 'udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1'
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(pipeline, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

You can add sprop-parameter-sets property into the caps between udpsrc and rtpjitterbuufer (that I've added here, without this it may fail to run without disabling sync) if SPS and PPS are not inserted into the stream:

```
pipeline = 'udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, media=video,encoding-name=H264, sprop-parameter-sets="Z0JAKpWgHgCJ+VA\\=\\,aM48gA\\=\\=" ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=500 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1 ' 
#or
pipeline = 'udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, media=video,encoding-name=H264, sprop-parameter-sets="Z0JAKpWgHgCJ+VA\=\,aM48gA\=\=" ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=500 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1 '
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have one queston, where did  'sprop-parameter-set' go in this new pipeline? isnt it important for UDP streams?

Comment: Edited my answer with further advice.

Comment: thank you very much I tried it today and its working!